# $\int \frac{\left(2x^3-4x^2-x-3\right)}{\left(x^2-2x-3\right)}dx$ confusion

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

$$\int \frac{\left(2x^3-4x^2-x-3\right)}{\left(x^2-2x-3\right)}dx$$
=$$x^2+3\ln \left(x-3\right)+2\ln \left(x+1\right)+C$$

Where did the $x^2$ come from?

What I did:

Partial fraction then integrate, got the answer without $x^2$ term.

Comment: When you divide the numerator and denominator so you can have a fraction to decompose, your quotient is $2x$

Comment: @Nitin Is the partial fraction A/(x-3) + B/(x+1)?

Comment: Yes because that is what the denominator factors as

Comment: so ... = A(x+1) + B(x-3)? Wheres 2x?

Comment: You first have to divide the numerator and denominator. You can do partial fractions once the numerator's degree is less than or equal to the denominator's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** It comes from the partial fraction decomposition, you have
$$
\frac{2x^3-4x^2-x-3}{x^2-2x-3}=2x+\frac2{x+1}-\frac3{x-3} \tag1
$$ giving
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{2x^3-4x^2-x-3}{x^2-2x-3}dx&=\int 2xdx+\int\frac2{x+1}dx-\int\frac3{x-3}dx\\\\
&=\color{red}{x^2}+\int\frac2{x+1}dx-\int\frac3{x-3}dx\\\\
&=\color{red}{x^2}+2 \ln|x+1|-3 \ln|x-3|+C.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

> $$\int \frac{\left(2x^3-4x^2-x-3\right)}{\left(x^2-2x-3\right)}dx$$

$$=\int\bigg(2x+\frac{3}{x-3}+\frac{2}{x+1}\bigg)dx$$

$$=2\int\frac{1}{x+1}dx+3\int\frac{1}{x-3}dx+2\int xdx$$

$$\boxed{\color{red}{=\color{blue}{x^2}+2 \ln|x+1|-3 \ln|x-3|+C}}$$